# What homotopy classes can attaching an $E_n$-cell kill?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads, higher-algebra

Let $A$ be a connected $E_{n+1}$-ring spectrum and let $\alpha\in\pi_k(A)$. I am having trouble showing that attaching an $E_n$-cell along $\alpha$ will necessarily not kill an element $\beta\in\pi_k(A)$ unless $\beta$ is a multiple of $\alpha$. Perhaps this is not true, but it seems plausible to me since attaching an $E_n$-cell seems like everything above the cell that kills $\alpha$ itself should be in higher dimensions.

To be precise: we can "attach an $E_n$-$A$-cell" to $A$ along $\alpha$ by taking the pushout of the following span in $E_n$-$A$-algebras: $$A\overset{\overline{0}}\leftarrow F_{E_n}(\Sigma^kA)\overset{\overline{\alpha}}\to A $$ where $F_{E_n}$ is the free $E_n$-$A$-algebra functor, $\overline{0}$ is the adjoint of the zero map $\Sigma^kA\to A$ and $\overline{\alpha}$ is the adjoint of the $A$-module map $\Sigma^kA\to A$ induced by $\alpha$.

It seems to me that there should be a "bottom layer" of $F_{E_n}(\Sigma^kA)$ that kills of $\alpha$, but that everything else (used to kill off the powers of $\alpha$ in a homotopy coherent way) should happen in higher dimensions, so cannot kill $\beta$. Is this true?

It may be useful to notice that, according to Lemma 4.4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7988.pdf) of Antolin-Camarena and Barthel, that the above pushout is equivalent to $Ind_0^n(cof(\Sigma^k A\to A))$ where $Ind_0^n$ is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $E_n$-$A$-algebras to $E_0$-$A$-algebras (where $E_0$-$A$-algebras here just means unital $A$-modules).

I should also mention that this is the pretty clearly the best we can do in general, since as Tyler pointed out in the comments it's relatively easy to attach a structured cell along something in degree $k$ and  kill something in degree $k+1$. And his  example is not rare either. I can construct an infinite family of ring spectra in which this occurs for arbitrarily large degrees, when only attaching $E_1$-$A$-cells.

Comment: Unfortunately not. For example, I'd expect that killing off $x$ also kills off brackets like $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ which may not be multiples of $x$ in homotopy. As another example, killing off 2 in the sphere spectrum in an $E_1$ way also kills the Hopf map $\eta$.

Comment: @TylerLawson: I think he asking the following: if $t \in \pi_k(A)$ maps to zero in $\pi_k(A//\alpha)$, is it then the case that $t = a_0 \alpha$, for some $a_0 \in \pi_0(A)$. (Note that $t$ and $\alpha$ live in the same degree.) Thus $\eta$ is not a counterexample, not sure if brackets might be.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time explaining this clearly. But I'm only really interested in things which are in the same degree as $\alpha$. So $\eta$ is not an issue.

Comment: Yeah so to be clear, since $\beta$ is also in $\pi_k$, it must be "multiples" by elements in $\pi_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, Jon, I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @tyler no worries there's a lot of text up there :)

Answer (score 7):

[I write $A//\alpha$ for the pushout computed in $E_n-A$-algebras, and $E/\alpha$ for the pushout computed in $A$-modules.]

Here is an attempt (for $k>0$), though I should make it clear that I consider myself an amateur at this. I number all my claims so misstakes are easier to point out :).

(1) The forgetful functor $E_n-A-Alg \to E_n-Alg$ has a left adjoint given by smashing with $A$.

(2) All forgetful functors in sight preserve sifted colimits.

(3) The pushout $A//\alpha$ can be computed as geometric realisation of a two-sided bar construction $|Bar_{F_{E_n}(\Sigma^k A)}(A, A)|$ This is a sifted colimit. We have $B_n := Bar_{F_{E_n}(\Sigma^k A)}(A, A)_n = A \vee_A [F_{E_n}(\Sigma^k A)]^{\vee_A n} \vee_A A$, where $\vee_A$ means the coproduct in $E_n-A$-algebras.

(4) The free algebra functors are left adjoint, so preserve colimits. It follows from (1) that $A \vee_A [F_{E_n}(\Sigma^k A)]^{\vee_A n} \vee_A A = G_{E_n}[(S^k)^{\vee n}]\wedge A$, where $G_{E_n}$ denotes the free $E_n-S$-algebra functor.

(5) We have $G_{E_n}(X) = \bigvee_{k \ge 0} E_n(k)_+ \times_{\Sigma_k}^h X^{\wedge k}$.

(6) Thus $B_n = E_n(0)_+ \wedge A \vee E_n(1)_+ \wedge [(S^k)^{\vee n}] \wedge A \vee B_n'$, where $B_n'$ is $2k$-connective and so $k$-connected. (This is where I use $k>0$.)

(7) Since $E_n(0)$ and $E_n(1)$ are contractible, we have $B_n = A \vee (\Sigma^k A)^{\vee n} \vee B_n'$. We thus get the following decomposition of $A//\alpha$ (as a cofiber sequence):
$$ |C_\bullet| \to A //\alpha \to  |B'_\bullet|. $$
Here $C_n = A \vee (\Sigma^k A)^{\vee n} \vee 0 = Bar_{\Sigma^k A}(A, 0)$ and so $|C_\bullet|$ is the cofiber of $\alpha$. On the other hand each $B'_n$ is $k$-connected and hence so is $|B'_\bullet|$. It follows that $\pi_i(A//\alpha) = \pi_i(A/\alpha)$ for $i \le k$.

edit: I did not check that the decompositions I write down are compatible with the simplicial structure maps. But note that there *is* a map $A/\alpha \to A//\alpha$ under the identity on $A$. To construct it, using that $F_{E_n}$ preserves colimits, by adjunction it suffices to factor $\bar{\alpha}: F_{E_n} \Sigma^k A \to A$ through $F_{E_n} \alpha$. But by definition $\bar{\alpha}$ is $F_{E_n} \Sigma^k A \xrightarrow{F_{E_n} \alpha} F_{E_n} A \xrightarrow{\eta} A$, where $\eta$ is the (co)unit of adjunction. Surely this must be the map I write down...

Comment: When you write $A/ \alpha$, what does it mean? Is it just the spectrum cofiber of $\mathrm S \xrightarrow{\alpha} A$? Because that can't be right, at the very least you must factor out all $\pi_0(A)\alpha$.

Comment: I mean the cofiber of $\Sigma^n A \to A$, which I suppose actually is $S^n \wedge A \to A \wedge A \to A$, where the last map is multiplication.

Comment: @TomBachmann it seems like maybe your proof implies that if you attach a cell along an element in $\pi_k$ for $k>1$, you'd get that nothing can be killed in degrees higher than $k$, since you're getting that $2k$-connectivity there. Does that seem right to you?

Comment: Well things can be killed in degree 2k and higher, right?, but I suppose the last line can be improved to "for $i<2k$"

Comment: @TomBachmann is it clear that all of those equivalences of $B_n$ are compatible with the face and degeneracy maps?

Comment: @JonathanBeardsley I have edited my post

Comment: I wrote an "answer" that's really just long comments on your answer, with a strategy to define the simplicial maps.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer but rather extended commentary on [Tom
Bachmann's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275820/644). I hope to
address some of Jon's comments on that answer.

## Bar constructions with respect to coproducts compute pushouts

First let me address Tom's point (3), that an instance of the
two-sided bar construction computes pushouts. This is probably
well-known but I had to think about it for a bit, so I'll include an
explanation in case it helps someone else. Also, this explanation
helps later with coherence issues for maps between simplicial objects.

The two-sided bar construction can be defined very generally, for a
monoid $M$ for some monoidal structure $\otimes$ together with
left and right $M$-modules $L$ and $R$. Now consider the special
case when $\otimes$ is given by the coproduct. In this case, the
monoidal structure on $M$ is unique, given by the fold $M \sqcup M
\to M$, and the module structures on $L$ and $R$ are given simply
by morphisms $M \to L$, $M \to R$. And the claim is that the
geometric realization of the bar construction is simply the pushout of
$R \leftarrow M \to L$.

One way to see that is to consider the functor $b : \mathrm{Span} \to
\Delta^\mathrm{op}$ where $\mathrm{Span} = \{ r \leftarrow m \to l
\}$ and $b(m \to l) = (d_0 : [1] \to [0])$ and $b(m \to r) =
(d_1 : [1] \to [0])$. It's not hard to check that the coproduct-based
bar construction $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Span}, \mathcal{C}) \to
\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C})$ is given by left Kan
extension along this functor $b$. The usual argument about left Kan
extending along the composite $\mathrm{Span} \to \Delta^\mathrm{op}
\to \ast$, shows that a span and its corresponding bar construction
have the same colimit.

## Defining the relevant map of simplicial $A$-modules

Instead of trying to check that Tom's maps are compatible with faces
and degeneracies, let's try to build simplicial maps wholesale. I'll
use $F : \mathrm{Mod}_A \to \mathrm{Alg}^{E_n}_{A}$ for the free
$E_n$-$A$-algebra functor defined on $A$-module spectra, and
$U : \mathrm{Alg}^{E_n}_{A} \to \mathrm{Mod}_A$ for the
corresponding forgetful functor.

The key ingredient in Tom's argument is a simplicial $A$-module
$B_{\bullet}$ whose geometric realization is $U(A/\!/\alpha)$, the
underlying $A$-module of the $E_n$-$A$-algebra in Jon's
question. By the previous section, the simplicial
$E_n$-$A$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\bullet} :=
\mathrm{Lan}_b(A\overset{\overline{0}}\leftarrow
{E_n}(\Sigma^kA)\overset{\overline{\alpha}}\to A)$ has geometric
realization given by the pushout of that span, $A /\!/ \alpha$.
Since the forgetful functor $U$ preserves geometric realizations,
the simplicial $A$-module $B_{\bullet} := U \circ
\mathcal{B}_{\bullet}$ will have $U(A /\!/ \alpha)$ as geometric
realization.

Now let $C_{\bullet} := \mathrm{Lan}_b(0 \leftarrow \Sigma^k A \to
A)$ be the coproduct-based bar construction in $\mathrm{Mod}_A$. We
want to define a morphism of simplicial $A$-modules $C_{\bullet}
\to B_{\bullet} = U \circ \mathcal{B}_{\bullet}$, or equivalently a
morphism of simplicial $E_n$-$A$-algebras $F \circ C_{\bullet}
\to \mathcal{B}_{\bullet}$. Now, since $F$ is a left adjoint it
preserves the left Kan extension defining $C_{\bullet}$, so $F
\circ C_{\bullet}$ is the bar construction for the span $F(0)
\leftarrow F(\Sigma^k A) \to F(A)$. The following diagram is a
natural transformation between that span and the one defining
$\mathcal{B}_{\bullet}\require{AMScd}$:
$$\begin{CD}
F(0) @<{F(0)}<< F(\Sigma^k A) @>{F(\alpha)}>> F(A) \\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV   @V{\mathrm{id}}VV     @V{\mu_A}VV \\
 A @<{\bar{0}}<< F(\Sigma^k A) @>{\bar{\alpha}}>> A \\
\end{CD}$$
This map of spans induces a simplicial map between their respective
bar constructions.

## The rest of the argument

I think that now the rest of Tom's argument runs fine: let
$B'_{\bullet}$ be the cofibre in simplicial $A$-modules of
$C_{\bullet} \to B_{\bullet}$. Now, without worrying about
compatibility with faces and degeneracies, you can identify for each
$n$ the map $C_n \to B_n$ to describe $B'_n$ and see that
$B'_n$ is $2k$-connective.

Comment: Can you or @Tom say why the map you construct here is the same map that picks out the relevant pieces in Tom's decomposition? It doesn't seem obvious to me.